# Taglist failed to generate tags in cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin, ctags

I'm new to vim and its lots of plugins. I heard that there is a plugin called "taglist" can help to list tags in code files. Then I downloaded the taglist zip and place taglist.vim in the "plugin" folder under .vim folder in cygwin. Add some configurations in .vimrc as tutorial says.
However, when I tried to open code file, it prompts
**"Taglist: Failed to generate tags for .../main.c

/bin/bash: /usr/bin/ctags: No such file or directory ^@"**

Then I realized that I didn't install the ctags. So I download the ctags58 zip file, unzip the folder to some place and add its path to PATH environment variable. In cygwin, when I type "$ctags --version", it can output expected results. But, when open a code file in vim, it still prompts the above error.

Here I want to ask for help on this 2 topics:

1. How to install just the missing ctags in cygwin? Each time I want to install some components, I should click every items in the package list, to install or to skip, that's very time-consuming and tough!
2. If I choose not to install ctags in cygwin setup, how can I eliminate the error prompts?

Comment: I did add "Hello all," at the text beginning, the post preview is ok, but after posted, why the words are filtered and always gone?!!! Changed to "Dear friends", gone too!!!

Comment: on (1), no you don't have to click all items: just run the setup.exe, and click 'Next' until you have the package list, then simply find the package you want to add and set it to install. It will leave all installed packages installed, maybe update some, and install your new package.
(2) make sure it is accessible from /usr/bin/ctags - create a symlink.. But i advise to use cygwin packages if available.

Comment: Hi @kenny, If I just select the "ctags" component in cygwin_setup.exe package list window and leave other components unchanged, then I will see it begin download other things that definitely not the "ctags" package, so I wonder it will download all active packages, especially the "Default" package. 
For example, in my previous setup, I "skip" the "Graphic" package, then in this setup, the package will be "default", so will it be downloaded and installed?

Comment: It will download and install dependencies. But make sure to click 'Finish' and exit the installer; if you click 'Back' after installing, and then 'Next' again, it will re-install the selected packages..

Comment: Hi @Kenney, thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Hi all, how can I mark this post as "Resolved" and close it?